# Creating a random order for my quiz questions

Tags: c#, list, random

I have created a quiz application and was using a switch statement to work my way through the questions. i.e. going from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 and so on.
However, once the user has completed the quiz once and wanted to start again, they would have to go through all the same questions all over again. (the design is that if they get one wrong, the application exits).
Therefore, I wanted to see if there was a way to either randomize the number for the *QuestionCount* (but only have this number generated once) or another way I could do it.
I can see there are suggestions in using a list but these seem to concentrate on large numbers contained in the list whereas mine currently will only be 20 questions long.

I have copied the code I am using currently.

```
private void Verify(int Question)
{
    switch (Question)
    {
        case 1:
            if (checkBox1.Checked && !checkBox2.Checked && !checkBox3.Checked && !checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Correct - Well Done");
                //This was a test to see if I could assign a random number which works but the number could then appear again meaning the user gets the same question
                Random random = new Random();
                QuestionCount = random.Next(0, 21);
                QuestionSelection(QuestionCount);
                //SelectLabel(QuestionCount);
                ClearcheckBox();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No - It was Sunguard");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (checkBox3.Checked && !checkBox2.Checked && !checkBox1.Checked && !checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                //this method was the original where it just adds 1 to QuestionCount and works it way through the switch statement for the questions.
                MessageBox.Show("Correct - Well Done");
                QuestionCount++;
                QuestionSelection(QuestionCount);
                //SelectLabel(QuestionCount);
                ClearcheckBox();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No - It's to look at a students details");
                Application.Exit();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "shuffle". That is, to randomly reorder a list without replacement. You want to shuffle a list of questions (in your code, questions appear to just be identified by `int`s, so a list of `int`s).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put all questions in a List, and shuffle it:

```
public List<T> RandomPermutation<T>(List<T> array)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    List<T> retArray = new List<T>(array);

    int maxIndex = array.Count - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++)
    {
        int swapIndex = random.Next(i, maxIndex);
        if (swapIndex != i)
        {
            T temp = retArray[i];
            retArray[i] = retArray[swapIndex];
            retArray[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    return retArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that each question is only asked once I would use two Lists: `AnsweredQuestions` and `UnansweredQuestions`.

At the beginning `AnsweredQuestions` is empty, `UnansweredQuestions` contains all questions to be asked.
Now you can you the randomizer like you already have it in your code above. As the max vlaue for the `random.Next()` you take the current item `Count` of the `UnansweredQuestions` list.

After the question was answered correctly, you can remove it from the `UnansweredQuestions` list and put it into the `AnsweredQuestions` list.

This way your randomizer only uses those questions that really are unanswered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will this still work with my questions being held in a switch statement too.

    private void QuestionSelection(int intQuestionNo)
        {
            switch (intQuestionNo)
           {
                case 1:
                labelQuestion.Text = "Who made Banner";
                checkBox1.Text = "Sungard";
                checkBox2.Text = "McDonalds";
                checkBox3.Text = "Asda";
                checkBox4.Text = "Apple";
                break;

Trying to put these questions into a list with the checkbox.text answers could prove a task right?

Comment: Sorry, getting the code into the comment box isn't great and as I am a new user, I can't create a new post for another 8 hours

Comment: @user1206484: I would not take that aproach at all because that is very unflexible. What would you do if you need to change the number of questions to, say, 50 or 1000? How about this: The random number is the index of you question in the 'UnansweredQuestions' list. The question the provides each answer and the correct solution as properties. You could then provide the question to a method that assigns those properties to the appropriate CheckBoxes. By doing it like this you get aflexible approach that never ever cares how many questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small number of possible values you can encode the choices as bit flags in a Uint64. I've added an example below that does it.

I use a BitArray for convenience. It would be better to use bit-wise & and | operators.
The result is packed into one UInt64, but it could as easily have been two separate Uint32 for flags and value.

```
private static UInt64 Next(UInt64 current, int questions)
{
    // Convert the current value to an array of bytes.
    // Remove the least significant 4 bytes.
    // and then create a flag array.
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(current);
    bytes[0] = bytes[1] = bytes[2] = bytes[3] = 0;
    var flags = new BitArray(bytes);

    // If all questions has been answered then exit with 0.
    var all = Enumerable.Range(32, questions).All(flags.Get);
    if (all)
        return 0UL;

    // Make a random next value, if the value has been used then repeat.
    var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    var next = random.Next(questions);
    while (flags.Get(next + 32))
        next = random.Next(questions);

    // set the flag value for the guess.
    flags.Set(next + 32, true);

    // convert the flags back to Uint64 and add the next value.
    flags.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0) + Convert.ToUInt64(next);
}
```

Test with:

```
var first = Next(0UL, 20);
while (first != 0UL)
{
    var v = first & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(v);
    first = Next(first, 20);
}
```